# When to use GraphQLID instead of GraphQLInt?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

It is not clear when to use [`GraphQLID`](http://graphql.org/docs/api-reference-type-system/#graphqlid) instead of [`GraphQLInt`](http://graphql.org/docs/api-reference-type-system/#graphqlint).

Consider the following schema:

```
type User {
  id: Int!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
}

type Query {
  user (id: ID!): User
}
```

In case of `Query.user`, it seem to make no difference whether to use `GraphQLID` or `GraphQLInt`.

In case of `User.id`, using `GraphQLID` will cast the input to string. Using `GraphQLInt` will ensure that the input is an integer.

This makes the query and type system inconsistent.

The [graphql-js](/questions/tagged/graphql-js)  [spec](http://graphql.org/docs/api-reference-type-system/#graphqlid) simply says:

> A `GraphQLScalarType` that represents an ID.

Is this an implementation detail (e.g. should GraphQL client cast `GraphQLID` to an integer when it can), or is it expected that `ID` is always a string in [graphql](/questions/tagged/graphql)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had a look at the GraphQL spec.

> The ID scalar type represents a unique identifier, often used to refetch an object or as the key for a cache. The ID type is serialized in the same way as a `String`; however, it is not intended to be human‐readable. While it is often numeric, it should always serialize as a `String`.

– https://spec.graphql.org/April2016/#sec-ID

That answers the question whether it is left to implementation or dictated by the spec, i.e. ID should be always serialized to a `String`.

In addition, in the context of an input type, input needs to be coerced into a string. From the spec:

> **Input Coercion**
>
> When expected as an input type, any string (such as `"4"`) or integer (such as `4`) input value should be coerced to ID as appropriate for the ID formats a given GraphQL server expects. Any other input value, including float input values (such as `4.0`), must raise a query error indicating an incorrect type.

That leaves me with the original problem.

I have a [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) backend where my PK are integers.

The way I see it, I have these options:

- Start using UUIDs for PKs. However, this has [performance implications](http://kccoder.com/mysql/uuid-vs-int-insert-performance/).
- Ignore the implicit requirement (originating in the [relayjs](/questions/tagged/relayjs) ecosystem) to have the ID unique across the application, and cast IDs to number when possible for internal consumption.
- <strike>Hash</strike> Encode IDs on the application data layer, e.g. <strike>UUID</strike> `base64` derived from a concatenation of table name & PK value.

I am going with the latter option. This is also the approach that [`graphql-relay-js`](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js) has adopted via [`toGlobalId`](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js#object-identification) and [`fromGlobalId`](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js#object-identification).