# Apollo/GraphQL not able to get referenced entities when asking for the ID

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

The stack:

- VueJS/Vuetify
- Apollo client
- Spring boot, MongoDB and GraphQL server

The issue I'm facing is, when I execute my GraphQL query using Apollo and there is a collection of referenced entities, grabbing all the fields **except** the `id` works fine, but as soon as I add

```
id {
   entityId
   organisationId
}
```

to also get the `id` fields, it returns a collection of all the same entity.

Let's say there is three users: John, Jane and Jen; specifically in this order. When I execute the query, it will return `John`'s object three times, **when the `id` is in the GraphQL query**. If the `id` **isn't** in the GraphQL query, it will return all the entities correctly.

When I execute the query through Postman, it works correctly. It seems to be an Apollo specific issue.

The `id` entity:

```java
public class TradelyId implements Serializable {
    String entityId;
    String organisationId;
}
```

**A few snippets that might help paint the picture:**

```java
@Document
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Assignment implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -165856150537588143L;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @NonNull
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private TradelyId id;

    @NotNull
    @NonNull
    private Instant startDateTime;

    @NotNull
    @NonNull
    private Instant endDateTime;

    @NotNull
    @NonNull
    @DBRef
    @ShallowReference
    private Job job;

    @NotNull
    @NonNull
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    @ShallowReference
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

```
type Assignment {
    id: TradelyId!
    startDateTime: String!
    endDateTime: String!
    job: Job!
    users: [User!]!
}

input AssignmentRefInput {
    id: TradelyIdQueryInput!
}

input AssignmentCreateInput {
    id: TradelyIdCreateInput!
    startDateTime: String!
    endDateTime: String!
    job: JobRefInput!
    users: [UserRefInput!]!
}

input AssignmentUpdateInput {
    id: TradelyIdQueryInput!
    startDateTime: String!
    endDateTime: String!
    job: JobRefInput!
    users: [UserRefInput!]!
}

extend type Mutation {
    createAssignment(assignment: AssignmentCreateInput!): TradelyId!
    updateAssignment(assignment: AssignmentUpdateInput!): TradelyId!
}

extend type Query {
    assignment(id: TradelyIdQueryInput!): Assignment
    assignments(id: String!): [Assignment!]!
    assignmentForJobId(id: TradelyIdQueryInput!): Assignment
    usersAvailableForAssignment(startDateTime: String!, endDateTime: String!): [User!]!
    assignmentsForUser: [Assignment!]!
}
```

Comment: If I've missed anything that might be of help, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#generating-unique-identifiers ... IDK if supported in vue apollo

Comment: @xadm Thanks for your reply, that was exactly what I was looking for. Once I figure out the answer, I will post it here and mention you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `typename` from the cache seems to work.

```js
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  addTypename: false,
});

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: '',
  cache: cache,
});
```

Comment: trick rather ... ID should be a scalar, not object (other type) ... common method is to base64 encode it https://stackoverflow.com/a/47132458